# Is pgfplot implemented using the TikZ data visualization library?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, sourcecode

Is the `pgfplot` package implemented in terms of the TikZ data visualization library, or are they independent of each other?

Comment: `pgfplots` was first uploaded to CTAN in 2008 (https://www.ctan.org/ctan-ann/pkg/pgfplots), while the `datavisualization` library was introduced in version 3 of TikZ, which was uploaded to CTAN six years later, in 2014 (https://www.ctan.org/ctan-ann/id/mailman.3064.1393532812.3883.ctan-ann@dante.de).

Comment: They are mentioned as alternatives in the Ti*k*Z manual (326 sec. 22).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No: you can verify this as the visualisation library for TikZ has to be loaded separately. If you do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

and search the `.log`you will find lines of the form

```
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/datavisualization/tikzlibrarydatavisualization.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarydatavisualization.code.tex 2015/05/18 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)
```

whereas with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

such lines are absent.

Comment: The data visualisation library has I think been developed to its current power only since `pgfplots` was released.

Comment: The conclusion is right, but I'm not sure about the reasoning since it could have been that `pgfplots` was based on the PGF libraries the Ti*k*Z stuff loads. It might be better to check if the PGF `datavisualization` module is loaded i.e. `pgfmoduledatavisualization.code.tex`.

Comment: @cfr Quite often the TikZ and `pgf` libraries are one and the same. Here, I checked the log for `visuali`: you don't see any files with that in their name when loading `pgfplots`.

Comment: Indeed. I just meant that in general, `grep`ping for the precise name of the Ti*k*Z library might be misleading, for example, so checking for the PGF module/library might be better. But `grep`ping for something like `visualiz` would obviously work, too.

Comment: I can confirm that Joseph's answer is correct: 1. the two are independent and 2. the DV library was developed a long time after pgfplots was stable.